# Serialize own class

Tags: java, android, class, serialization

i'm experiencing some problems with the serialization of Java and haven't found my Error.
I want to serialize my class, save it and read it again. This is the class i want to serialize:

```
public class MusicItem implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 6429052113846297403L;
  public String title;
  public String album;
  public String artist;
  public String art;
  public String musiclocation;
}
```

And when i want to write it i get the following error:

```
08-07 14:21:37.723: W/System.err(9557): java.io.NotSerializableException:  de.godev.gomusic.MainActivity
```

I hope you can help me.

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Read the error: you're not serializing the class you posted: **de.godev.gomusic.MainActivity**. Side-note: awful data encapsulation.

Comment: You'll need to show us the code that tries to do the serialization; I think you'll find it's not doing what you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

The class which is not getting serialized is de.godev.gomusic.MainActivity

Please post the source of MainActivity class as well

Comment: MainActivity is the class from which im saving and im having all the main functions in there :( Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If `MusicItem` is an inner class, you should make it static. An inner class maintains a reference to the object that it's contained in, and if you try to serialize it, the containing object has to be serialized as well.

To make a nested class static declare it with the `static` keyword:

```
public static class MusicItem implements ...
```

Comment: That sounds logic, but it's giving me an Illegal Modifiers Exception

Comment: Is `MusicItem` or an inner class or not?

Comment: No its not. Would it help to make it one?

Comment: Oh i didnt see the if in your question. :D

Comment: In that case you can't get the error you report for trying to serialize an instance of it. You should add to your question the part of the code where you try to serialize the object.